# What is actually meant by parallel_iterations in tfp.mcmc.sample_chain?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I am not able to get what does the parameter `parallel_iterations` stand for in sampling multiple chains during MCMC.

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/mcmc/sample_chain) for mcmc.sample_chain() doesn't give much details, it just says that

> The parallel iterations are the number of iterations allowed to run in parallel. It must be a positive integer.

I am running a NUTS sampler with multiple chains while specifying `parallel_iterations=8`.

Does it mean that the chains are **strictly** run in parallel? Is the parallel execution dependent on multi-core support? If so, what is a good value (based on the number of cores) to set `parallel_iterations`? Should I naively set it to some higher value?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow can unroll iterations of while loops to execute in parallel, when some parts of the data flow (I.e. iteration condition) can be computed faster than other parts. If you don't have a special preference (i.e. reproducibility with legacy stateful samplers), leave it at default.